# Folder icon is not coming in EXTJs 4.1 tree panel

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4.1

I created a ExtJs 4.1 tree panel. When I create the tree using [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1v5), I see the folder icon but when I create the tree panel in my app, folder icons are not coming. I think its folder path issue. I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702968/extjs4-treepanel-icon-issue) and it talks about setting some CSS class to get the desired result. My question is why in my application, folder icons are not shown and how can I check on which path system in searching for these icons?

I have not set\updated any CSS path in the fiddle but the images are appearing properly.

Comment: have you looked in chrome developer tools/firebug to see if the files are trying to be loaded but failing (404)? (in network tab)  That may hold some clue as to where the files are being referenced.  This info is available on network tab in chrome.

Comment: @weeksdev: Thank you for reply. I did checked firebug but no luck :(